# How to rotate an image towards cursor location?

Tags: java, swing, rotation, position, graphics2d

I'm trying to rotate an image towards cursor location (the spin supposed to be from the center of the image and spin across itself towards cursor location)

```
    public void rotateImg(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g.create();

        int cursorX = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x - panel.getLocationOnScreen().x; // Mouse pos
        int cursorY = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y - panel.getLocationOnScreen().y;
        Point center = new Point(x+size/2,y+size/2); //Image center (x,y are the player's coordinates)
        double dx = cursorX - center.getX();
        double dy =cursorY - center.getY();

        System.out.println(Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(dx,dy)));

        g2.rotate(Math.toRadians(Math.atan2(dy,dx)),center.x,center.y);
        g2.drawImage(playerImage,x,y,size,size, null);
    }
```

this function is running inside a thread so it never stops and I checked to see if the cursor positions are updating (they are) and so is the angle but when I run it it barely spins and cant even make a 45 degrees rotation

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried this:

```
public void rotateImg(Graphics g)
    {
        double degrees;
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g.create();

        Point center = new Point(x+size/2,y+size/2); //Image center (x,y are the player's coordinates)
        int cursorX = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x - panel.getLocationOnScreen().x; // Mouse pos
        int cursorY = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y - panel.getLocationOnScreen().y;
        double dx = cursorX - center.getX();
        double dy = cursorY - center.getY();

        degrees = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(dy,dx))+90;

        g2.rotate(Math.toRadians(degrees),center.x,center.y);
        g2.drawImage(playerImage,x,y,size,size, null);
    }
```

it worked!